# Which X509 Certificate for Ubuntu Do I Require for Shim UEFI Key Management

Tags: boot, uefi, certificates

Can people please let me know what selections I need to for this - I select enroll from disk and then  am presented some .efi entries to choose from.

Any ideas/help on what I need to do here as I am not sure what this X509 Certificate is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to enroll a key for use by Shim or directly by your firmware as a Secure Boot key, you need a key file with a filename ending in `.der` or `.cer`. The `.efi` files your file browser is showing are EFI program files, which are *not* suitable. (You would select such files if you were enrolling a *hash*, which is what that the competing PreLoader utility uses.)

For more on this topic, see my [page on managing Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) or my related [page on controlling Secure Boot more completely.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/controlling-sb.html)